# How to create Empty List for two dimensional array in Flutter

Tags: flutter

But this don't work, as IDE says that "List is not a type". Then from the article, I tried to use this:

```
var lines = List.generate(0, (i) => List.generate(0, (j) => MyClass(), growable: true), growable: true);
```

Please Help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<List<MyClass>> myclasses2 = [[]];
```

may be the answer, I think

I think, this is better.

Comment: you best practice https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/List/List.html